# Query two custom objects joining on the Name field

Tags: salesforce, soql

I want to create a join on two custom objects joining on the Name field. Normally joins require a lookup or master-detail relationship between the two objects, but I just want to do a text match.

I think this is a Salesforce limitation but I couldn't find any docs on whether this was so. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can make a join (with dot notation or as subquery) only if there's a relationship present. And relationships (lookup or master-detail) can be made only by Id. There are several "mutant fields" (like Task.WhoId) but generally speaking you can't write a JOIN in SOQL and certainly can't use a text column as a foreign key.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#relate_query_limits

> Relationship queries are not the same as SQL joins. You must have a
>   relationship between objects to create a join in SOQL.

There are some workarounds though. Why exactly do you need the join?

**Apex / SOQL** - have a look at [SOQL in apex - Getting unmatched results from two object types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718097/soql-in-apex-getting-unmatched-results-from-two-object-types) for example. Not the prettiest thing in the world but it works. If you want to try something really crazy - [SOSL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_examples.htm) that would search your 2 objects at the same time?

**Reports** - you should have no problem grouping by text field - that means a [joined report](http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_joined_format_overview.htm) might give you results you're after. Since Winter'13 joined reports allow charts and exporting, that was quite a limiting factor...

**Easy building of links between data** - use external ids and upsert operation, especially if you plan to load data from outside SF easily. Check my answer for [Can I insert deserialized JSON SObjects from another Salesforce org into my org?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909447/can-i-insert-deserialized-json-sobjects-from-another-salesforce-org-into-my-org)

**Uniqueness constraints** - you can still mark fields as required & unique.

**Check against "dictionary" of allowed values** - Validation rule with [VLOOKUP](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#VLOOKUP) might do what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I have a few custom objects that use the Name field as a foreign key for the external system it works with. The solution I ended up using works like your suggestion in `SOQL in apex - Getting unmatched results from two object types`